# Error trying to send email: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: net_io_connectionclosed after 5 emails

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I'm having a problem trying to send several emails in my web app.
The thing is that I can send ALWAYS 5 mails correctly, and when I'm trying to send to 6th one, I get an exception like this:

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Error al enviar correo. ---> System.IO.IOException: No se puede escribir datos de en la conexión de transporte: net_io_connectionclosed.

Points to consider:

- Obviously is not a problem of firewall, because it sends correctly the first 5 mails.
- I'm working with the 3.5 framework, which does not allow me to Dispose the smptclient.
- The process runs in a thread (I made it run as a normal function and I get the same exception).
- I attach a little pdf to the mail, but I've tried without it and I still get the same exception.
- I've triend setting: smtpClient.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 1;
- Also tried: smtpClient.ServicePoint.MaxIdleTime = 1;
- My question is similar to this (last reply 2011, no solution yet): https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/db6a2f36-9f7a-448d-89b8-968d45e13b45/systemnetmailsmtpexception-netioconnectionclosed?forum=netfxnetcom

```
    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user","Password");
    smtpClient.Port = 25;
    smtpClient.Host = "host";

    smtpClient.Send(email);
```

Comment: are you sending files or just text emails ? or what is the size of your email ?

Comment: I'm sending a short mail with a pdf attached (50kb)